# Can I prefix a function with "get" in Springboot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, repository

I have a Mcq class associated to a MongoRepository, and I want to get an instance of my Mcq which apply several changes (Answers shuffle, Questions draw, etc). I declared my function "myMcq.getInstance()", but I can't do that because every time I want to send a Mcq in a ResponseEntity there is an error in the JSON output because Springboot thinks that there is a "instance" property in my class.

Here is my java class :

```
@Document(collection = "Mcqs")
public class Mcq {
    @Id public String id;
    @DBRef public User creator;

    public String title;
    public String categoryID;
    public List<McqChapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Difficulty difficulty;

    public Mcq() {}

    public Mcq(String title) {
        this();
        this.title = title;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getQuestionsIDs() {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (McqChapter chapter : chapterList) result.addAll(chapter.getQuestionIDs());

        return result;
    }


    public McqInstance getInstance() {
        return new McqInstance(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add @JsonIgnore on getInstance() method

Comment: And/or add @JsonIgnoreType on same method

Comment: Oh thanks, I knew it could be used for properties, I didn't thought it would works for functions too !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the error add [@JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) to `getInstance()` method:

```
@JsonIgnore 
public McqInstance getInstance() {
    return new McqInstance(this);
}
```

> Marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field is to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality. That is, it should not be consider a "getter", "setter" or "creator".

Comment: Why should I use `@JsonIgnoreType` instead of `@JsonIgnore` ?

Comment: I fixed the typo